# JS: convention to distinguish immediate vs async methods

Tags: javascript, async, naming-standards

I normally have a *laissez faire* attitude on method naming conventions but now I am working on a module in JavaScript that will have some methods that can return the value directly (immediate / plain function), and others that must be asynchronous and work through callbacks / promises / etc.

I think it would be preferable for the method names to make it plain which is which.  Is there any such naming convention out there already?

Or should I just use callbacks even for the methods that do not require it?

Comment: I don't know whether there's a convention. In the worst case you can establish one for your code. I wouldn't recommend using callbacks for everything. They make code more difficult to read and write. It's a price JavaScript requires you to pay for asynchrony. It doesn't make sense to pay the price and get nothing in return.

Comment: In the (modern) C# world, methods that are asynchronous typically have names that end with "Async", e.g. "ReadFileAsync".

Comment: Alternatively, in a NodeJS world, often the synchronous methods end in "sync".

Answer (score 3):

There is no one convention fits all here, you may go though several style guides and get your answer but they will probably give you different answers based on the personal experience of the author.

For callbacks (button clicks, event etc..) it is common to use the `on` prefix on the method name, it usually hints the method/function is a callback that will run `on` a certain event

```
function onClick(event) { ... }
```

HTML elements even provide such naming, for example, [`input#onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) when an input's value is modified, or the [`window#onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) callback that is fired when the window is loaded.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="" onchange="onChange()">
```

**JS**

```
function onChange() {
    console.log("i was changed");
}
```

For promises there is no specific naming convention, but you can attach a hint to the variable name

```
var getDataPromise = new Promise(...);
```

Of course A+ complaint promises must implement the [`.then`](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-then-method) method that also hints that your function returns a promise.

I've also seen developers attach `Async` when they have 2 version of the same function

```
function getData() {...}
function getDataAsync() {...}
```

And to clear up any other ambiguity, it's a good practice to keep comments in code or write documentations that explain what each function/method accepts and returns.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing seems to already be in the works for ES2017 called [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) functions.  So the "async" keyword would make it perfectly clear what type of function it is.  Although use of this "async" doesn't guarantee it is asynchronous, it clearly *could* be potentially.

In the meantime, I see nothing wrong with going by the C# convention mentioned by @DerekElkins and adding an Async to the end of function names which are intended to be called asynchronously.

Comment: technically you are right, but not all asynchrnous functions are `async function`s, it's just an abstraction that you can do without it (that is, if you really like chaining `.then` methods) and you're still left with the task of naming it "right"

Comment: Even when a function is defined using `async function`, it's still just a normal function that happens to (probably) return a promise. So a naming convention can still be helpful, rather than expecting callers to look at its implementation.